# jQuery error?? How to get the first "td" in all rows that are visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I am hiding some rows.  I want to get the first td in all of the rows that are showing.  I have the following statement

```
$("table.SimpleTable tbody tr:visible td:first-child");
```

this works in FireFox but not in IE any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am running the code on a click event.  The html that you have written is pretty much spot on but for the some reason unknown to me it is not working.  I have found a work around though.  (I am trying to get a comma delimited string of all values in the first td for the visible rows)  Anyway the following work around gets the job done.

```
    var notfirst = false;
    var serials = "";
    var tds = $("table.SimpleTable tbody tr:visible td:first-child");
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        var td = $(tds[i]);
        if (td.is(":hidden"))
            continue;
        if (notfirst)
            serials += ",";
        else
            notfirst = true;

        serials += $.trim(td.text());
    }
```

For some reason the :hidden tag works correctly but not the :visible in IE7

Answer (score 6):

That *should* work. With HTML that looks like this:

```
<table class='SimpleTable'> 
  <tr style='display: none;'> 
    <td>test1</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>test2</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>test3</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr style='display: none;'> 
    <td>test4</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>test5</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>test6</td> 
  </tr>   
</table>
```

Doing this:

```
$("table.SimpleTable tbody tr:visible td:first-child").css('color','red');
```

Makes the color red in Firefox, IE7 for me. What does your HTML look like?

[Here's what I tested the above on](http://jsbin.com/ekuyu)

**EDIT**: It is very weird to me that you need to do what you're doing right now. You should be able to replace what you have right now with this:

```
var serials = [];
$("table.SimpleTable tbody tr:visible td:first-child").each(function() {
    serials.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});
var serials = serials.join(',');
```

If the TDs are being populated from the selector they should only be the visible ones. If you are getting hidden TDs into the serials (which, I must stress, should really not be happening and is a bug or a sign of an error somewhere), try this selector instead:

```
$("table.SimpleTable tbody tr:not(:hidden) td:first-child")
```

Comment: When I get the chance I will try the selector you have mentioned.   I do however like the serails.push() and the serials.join(",") much better than what I have and will implement that for sure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation:

> "How :visible is calculated was
>   changed in jQuery 1.3.2. Element
>   assumed as visible if it and its
>   parents consumes space in document.
>   CSS visibility isn't taken into
>   account."

Maybe this has something to do with it. Try using a class selector or something instead of tr:visible

Answer (score 3):

why don't you split it up a bit?

```
$("table.SimpleTable").find("tr:visible").find("td:first-child").text()
```

?